# KeyError: ('', 'occurred at index 0')

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

This piece of code that has these columns: `index, area, key0`

I have these columns:

```
index, area, key0
```

I have to group by index (it is a normal column called index) in order to take the rows that have the same value.

```
#all the ones, all the twos, etc
```

Some of them (rows) are unique though.
About the ones that are not unique now:
What I have done so far:
I have to check with a group by which of the groups have the largest area and give its respected `key0` value to the others in its group in a new column called `key1`. 
The unique values are going to still have the same value they had in `key0` in the now `key1` column

```
df["rank_gr"] = df.groupby("index")["area"].rank(ascending = False, method = 
"first")
df["key1_temp"] = df.apply(lambda row: str(row["key0"]) if row["rank_gr"] == 1.0 
else (""), axis = 1)
df["key1"] = df.groupby("index")["key1_temp"].transform("sum")
print (df[["area", "index", "key0", "key1"]])


# expected OUTPUT
area  index key0 key1
  50      1   1f    5
  60      2    2    6
  70      3   3d   3d
  80      5    4    4
  90      1    5    5
 100      2    6    6
  10      3    7   3d
  20      3    8   3d
  70      3    9   3d
```

gives this:

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
KeyError: ('', 'occurred at index 0')
```

The lines that give error are these:

```
df["key1_temp"] = df.apply(lambda row: str(row["key0"]) if row["rank_gr"] == 1.0 
    else (""), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `python3`? The `print` in 4th row tells it's `python2`. In `Python 3.6`, `pandas 0.23.0` the code doesn't raise any exception

Comment: In which line you are getting an error?

Comment: the code was python 2 and I tried to turn it to python 3. What need to be fixed?

Comment: @Mohamed Thasin ah updated the question with where the error occurs

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do or what your expected output is.

Comment: check the first lines that describe the expected result

Comment: I didn't understand that. Can you either rephrase or show your expected output?

Comment: I improved the question you can observe the new version